# OkHttp - detect image download timeout

Tags: java, android, android-glide, okhttp

In my android app I using glide for image loading and OkHttp for network operations.

I would like to show error image using glide if image download takes longer than timeout (eg. 10s). I used GlideModule to connect OkHttpClient with glide but it seems that readTimeout method from OkHttpClient is not working as I thought - it's not waiting for image download completion but it's only waiting for bytes to read.

So my question is: How I can abort okhttp request if image download operation takes more than set timeout? I tried to do this in Interceptor but without success for that moment.

Comment: Re: "readTimeout ... is not working as I thought". Me too.

Re: "it's only waiting for bytes to read". I've asked for clarification: "[OkHttp readTimeout start and stop events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76917995/1334619)"

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t implemented in OkHttp. We’re tracking [whole operation timeouts here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2840).

If you’re impatient you can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` or similar to cancel the call after a specified duration.