# OkHttp readTimeout start and stop events?

Tags: okhttp

What are the start and stop events for the OkHttp `readTimeout`?

My initial thoughts, which I now suspect are naive, were that the read timeout clock would:

- **Start** when the HTTP client completes writing (sending) the request to the server
- **Stop** when the HTTP client completes reading (receiving) the response from the server

From the [OkHttp docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/read-timeout/):

> The read timeout is applied to both the TCP socket and for individual read IO operations including on Source of the Response

I gather from this description that `readTimeout` "is applied" in more than one context:

- To an object (TCP socket)
- To operations, plural ("individual read IO operations including on Source of the Response")

but this tells me nothing explicitly about the start and stop events for the timeout in each context. Perhaps the writer thought that information was so obvious that it wasn't necessary to state it. However, it's not obvious to me, hence this question.

Googling for an answer finds the web page "[A Quick Guide to Timeouts in OkHttp](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-timeouts)", which presents the following description of `readTimeout`:

> A read timeout is applied from the moment the connection between a client and a target host has been successfully established.

If this is true, then it means that `readTimeout` also applies to the *writing of the request*, which occurs after connection. I find this confusing in the context of a timeout for an HTTP client: I would expect such timeouts to align with HTTP-level events.

And:

> It defines a maximum time of inactivity between two data packets when waiting for the server's response.

"Packet" as in *TCP segment* or as in *IP packet*?

Either way, if this is true, then it means that `readTimeout` violates the abstraction barrier. I shouldn't need to set an HTTP timeout based on the delay between the arrival of each turtle carrying a bit on its back.

But let's suppose it's true. "inactivity between two data packets"? When waiting for a response from the server, what's the *first* of those two data packets? Is it, implicitly, the *last* data packet of the request sent to the server? Or is "response"—bearing in mind the context: an HTTP client—being used here in a different, lower-level sense, not "HTTP response"? I'm left guessing.

Returning to my original question, then: what are the start and stop events for `readTimeout`?

I have a similar question about `writeTimeout` that I suppose I could ask in a separate question. When answering, please feel free to cover both `readTimeout` and `writeTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start event is an attempt by application code to fetch a single byte from the operating system’s TCP receive buffer. No read timeout can occur without an attempt to read from this buffer.

The end event is 1 or more bytes returned to the application (no timeout) or the timeout duration elapsing (timeout).

For HTTP/1 this capability is implemented by the OS in its TCP stack. When the application code wants to read data (the HTTP response metadata or any bytes of its body), this timeout is configured on the socket.

For HTTP/2 this capability is implemented in OkHttp’s multiplexing code on the response metadata and body.

This timeout is most useful in failing HTTP calls that stall due to application layer or network problems. For example, it can be used to fail if packets aren’t flowing.

I prefer the call timeout feature, which applies to the entire HTTP call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your work on OkHttp. To confirm I understand, in the context of using the OkHttp `execute` function to invoke an HTTP/1.1 request... `readTimeout` cannot be relied on to time out a response, because the server might return the response, such as a large image, in multiple chunks. Assembling the complete response (all chunks) might involve multiple reads of the TCP receive buffer. readTimeout applies to each read attempt. The elapsed time between (a) the read attempt for the first chunk and (b) the last chunk arriving could be much longer than readTimeout. Am I close?

Comment: Again, to confirm I understand, and given the same context (OkHttp `execute` function invoking an HTTP/1.1 request): even if the HTTP response _isn't_ chunked at the application layer, OkHttp might need several attempts at reading the TCP receive buffer before it has the complete response, right? And each read attempt involves a separate `readTimeout`. I've looked at the OkHttp code in GitHub to see how it handles frequency of read attempts, but that was a rabbit hole for me.

Comment: `writeTimeout` is similar to `readTimeout`, in the sense that it times out an attempt to write to the OS's TCP _send_ buffer, correct? In the context of using the OkHttp `execute` function to invoke an HTTP/1.1 POST request, can one rely on `writeTimeout` to time out a request (a very large request body)? Does OkHttp write the entire request to the TCP send buffer in a single attempt? Or... can `execute` (automatically?) chunk (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) a request, which might (?) involve multiple writes to the TCP send buffer, hence spreading one request over more than one `writeTimeout`?

Comment: Re: "I prefer the call timeout"; me too!