# How does OkHttp regulate the frequency of attempts to read from the TCP receive buffer?

Tags: okhttp

I'm specifically interested in the context of using the OkHttp `execute` function to invoke an HTTP/1.1 POST request.

This question is a follow-on to my earlier question, "[OkHttp readTimeout start and stop events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76917995/1334619)", to which [Jesse Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40013/jesse-wilson) answered (thanks again!):

> The start event is an attempt by application code to fetch a single byte from the operating system’s TCP receive buffer. No read timeout can occur without an attempt to read from this buffer.
>
> The end event is 1 or more bytes returned to the application (no timeout) or the timeout duration elapsing (timeout).

Given that answer: suppose that 1 or more bytes are returned to OkHttp, but not the complete response. What determines the timing of OkHttp's *next* attempt to read from the TCP receive buffer? For example, does OkHttp make the next attempt immediately, or is there a timed delay?

Comment: It gives you whatever came across the socket before the timeout.  TCP sockets don't work in packets, so even if the sender sends 1,000 bytes, you might get it 100 bytes at a time.  That's not usually an issue when the timeout is reasonable.

Comment: Yes, that matches what I've seen in logs from a test where the server deliberately wrote the response one byte at a time, with a delay of 9 seconds between each byte, and the OkHttp client had a read timeout of 10 seconds. The entire call (the complete request, including the response) took an elapsed time of several minutes: it completed successfully because no single read timed out, and the call timeout was unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp reads up to 8 KiB on each system call. This is the size of the byte arrays that back Okio’s Buffers.

Within this 8 KiB is HTTP metadata (headers, status codes, chunking, etc.).

It’ll make these system calls as necessary driven by the application’s calls to read the response body. If the application layer isn’t reading the response body, then OkHttp won’t read the inbound socket.

Typically applications process this immediately, by parsing the response body or otherwise processing it.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. From the OkHttp docs: "the execute function blocks until the response can be processed or is in error". I infer that, barring timeout or some other error, the execute function assembles the complete response before returning. Correct?
In this context (execute, blocking), OkHttp regulates the frequency of attempts to read from the TCP receive buffer. That's the specific context that I'm interested in here. With apologies, in hindsight, perhaps I should have asked, "How does the OkHttp _execute function_ regulate the frequency of attempts to read from the TCP receive buffer?"

Comment: ... for example, I imagine that, after reading one or more bytes from the TCP receive buffer, the execute function (that is, the underlying code that implements that function) decides whether or not the response is complete. If the response is incomplete, then... does the execute function _immediately_ perform another read? Or is there some (small but deliberate) delay before the next read attempt?